# Expected number of unique items between 2 subsets

Tags: probability, random-variables

Please help ASAP final in an hour and don't get this review question. There are two people at a donut shop that serves 10 different types of donuts. Both the people order a 5 donut subset (no 2 donut in their order is the same type). I know that means 10 choose 5 = 252 different possible orders. Now multiple parts to this question, but the part I don't get is how to find the expected number of donuts between two people (i.e. the number of unique types of donuts between the 2 orders).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will **assume** that each person orders $5$ types at random, and that their choices are independent. Neither assumption is mentioned explicitly in the question. Without some assumptions we cannot answer the question.

Let $X_i=1$ if doughnut of type $i$ is ordered by both, and let $X_i=0$ otherwise. Then the number of common types is $X_1+\cdots +X_{10}$ and by the linearity of expectation the expected number of common types is $E(X_1)+\cdots+E(X_{10})$

The probability doughnut of type $i$ is ordered by both is $\left(\frac{5}{10}\right)^2$.  So $E(X_i)=\left(\frac{5}{10}\right)^2$, and the expected number of common choices is $10\cdot \left(\frac{5}{10}\right)^2$.

Comment: Makes sense, E(X) computes to 2.5 which is the answer on the solutions page. Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome. The method of *indicator* random variables that we used is powerful, and bypasses the calculation of the distribution of the number of common choices. In this case, we *could* find the distribution, and then the expectation, but that would be quite a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

So you have persons $A$ and $B$. Enter $C$ who consistently picks the five flavours $B$ does *not* pick. Let $E_B$, $E_C$ be the expected number of donouts shared by $A$ and $B$, and by $A$ and $C$, repsectively. What can you say about $E_B, E_C$? (Their difference, their sum)?

Comment: 5 >= EB - EC >= 0 and 5 =< EB + EC =< 10

Answer (score 0):

I preassume that you are after the expectation of total different types of donuts that are chosen. Correct me if I am wrong.

For donut $i$ let $X_i$ take value $1$ if it is chosen by at least one of persons and let it take value $0$ otherwise. Then the total number of donuts chosen is $$X=X_1+\cdots+X_{10}$$ Consequently we have on base of linearity of expectation: $$\mathbb X=\mathbb EX_1+\cdots+\mathbb EX_{10}$$ 
That leads to $$\mathbb X=10\mathbb P(X_1=1)$$
Can you find $\mathbb P(X_1=1)$?